# Group Summary In crystal report in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

i want to get summary in that group. i got grouping correctly but for group summary it gives only last row so please help me out

[Required O/P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFgkj.jpg)

[Expected outpput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkW81.jpg)

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPY4L.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz7WL.jpg)

Comment: Where are numbers in your output also please explain where you are struck.. These type of questions will be closed automatically but are lucky its not closed till now

Comment: Sir, Nos are enclosed in expected output click on it. also what i want is enclosed in Required O/P. i just want id nos of male and id nos of female in that city but when i group using gender that will only show last id not all ids of male or female

Comment: check answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Group by City

Now create a formula `@Initialise', Place in group header

```
Shared Stringvar concatenate_male;
Shared Stringvar concatenate_female;

concatenate_male:="";
concatenate_female:="";
```

Create one more formula `@Concatenate` place in detail where you will get mail and female gender.

```
Shared Stringvar concatenate_male;
Shared Stringvar concatenate_female;

if Gender = "male"
then 
concatenate_male:=concatenate_male+ToText(STID)+", "
else if Gender="female"
then
concatenate_female:=concatenate_female+ToText(STDID)+", ";

1;
```

Place in details and supress take care this should be last field in detail section.

Now one more formula `@display`, place the formula in Group footer.

```
Shared Stringvar concatenate_male;
Shared Stringvar concatenate_female;

"Male:"+concatenate_male;
"Female:"+concatenate_female;
```

Try and let me know.